# Regular expression to find strings between special characters using QRegExp

Tags: regex, qt, qregexp

I want to match the `Property Name` and `Property value` in the string below

`#Property Name : Property Value`

The `Property Name` and `Property Value` are single/multi-worded sentence with numbers and spaces only. No special characters in them.

I tried with `(?<=#)(.*):(.*?)` but it is not working. I read through many of the questions in this website and tried them, but none seemed to work.

I expect the answer to use `QRegExp` (RegEx class of Qt) of qt4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO this is better:

`^#\s*([^:]+?)\s*:\s*(.*?)\s*$`

https://regex101.com/r/pW3wV4/3

[See this](https://regex101.com/r/pW3wV4/4) to why my solution is better (same reg exp but  more test cases).

Comment: Thanks. This works too! Can you explain why your expression is better? As I see it takes care of the leading and trailing spaces and also other special characters. Is that it?

Comment: [here are examples proving why my regexp is better](https://regex101.com/r/pW3wV4/4). Give more data so it could be even more polished.

Comment: Awesome example. Thanks again! It covers all my requirements

Comment: this is not working now. `QRegExp.isvalid()` returns `false`. So the regex is not running in qt. But it is working in online regex editors. Any help to solve the issue?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you've messed up the back slashes. Create new question with complete code, and add link here. Note [there is new API](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/729656/Reasons-to-abandon-and-replace-QRegExp-in-your-Qt) in Qt5: `QRegularExpression`.

Comment: Thanks Marek. I have to escape the back slashes. Thanks again. It is working after escaping the back slashes in QRegExp.

Comment: We can make QRegExp take care of backslashes using the QRegExp::escape(QString) function.

Comment: NOOOOOOO. `QRegExp::escape` is for scenario when you build regular excretion from unknown data (for example provided by end user). Here you have problem how string literal is build in `C`! In string literals back slash has special meaning so you can type into a string a special characters like "\n" "\t" and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following regex

```
^#([a-zA-Z0-9 ]*) : ([a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)$
```

demo here: https://regex101.com/r/gS7rF5/2

Comment: @Amen, Thanks, it works! But I don't know why `(?<=#)(.*):(.*)` which worked in the online regex tester didn't work for QRegExp. Any ideas?

Comment: I will wait for some other answers to the question for a while.